# Python: Tkinter TclError: can't invoke "image" command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, compiler-errors, spyder

*preface*: I have currently tried most things and there are few qusestions asked on stackoverflow on this question and i cant seem to wrap my head around it so im going to need some help

***application***: the purpose of this program is to animate an oval and a picture, the oval works fine, but the picture is struggling, you could remove the image or *alien2* and the program should run fine.

## CODE

[*image form*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZVPP.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from PIL import Image,ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageTk

class alien(object):
     def __init__(self):


        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=400, height = 400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.cardPath = Image.open('bubble.png')
        self.resCard = cardPath.resize((100,100))
        self.CardVar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resCard,master=root)
        self.alien1 = self.canvas.create_oval(20, 260, 120, 360, outline='white',fill='blue')
        self.alien2 = self.canvas.create_image(100,100,CardVar,anchor=CENTER)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.root.after(0, self.animation)
        self.root.mainloop()


     def animation(self):
        track = 0
        while True:
            x = 5
            y = 0
            if track == 0:
               for i in range(0,51):
                    time.sleep(0.025)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien1, x, y)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien2, x, y)
                    self.canvas.update()
               track = 1
               print("check")

            else:
               for i in range(0,51):
                    time.sleep(0.025)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien1, -x, y)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien2, -x, y)
                    self.canvas.update()
               track = 0
            print(track)

alien()
```

---

## ERROR:

[*image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRQCd.png)

> runfile('/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3/animation_test.py', wdir='/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3/animation_test.py', wdir='/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3')
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3/animation_test.py", line 57, in 
>       alien()
>
> File "/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3/animation_test.py", line 25, in **init**
>       self.CardVar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resCard,master=root)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 124, in **init**
>       self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 3542, in **init**
>       Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 3498, in **init**
>       self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
>
> TclError: can't invoke "image" command: application has been destroyed

---

I know the code is not beautiful, but it's a test environment and as mentioned everything should work flawless, but it breaks when an image is used instead of an oval which should not make a big difference. Thanks in advance!

---

## PROBLEM SOLVED

turns out the problem turned up when assigning *master* inside *PhotoImage()*, when i removed that the application did not get the *TclError*

## NEW PROBLEM

> the changes i made to the code were from this:

```
        self.cardPath = Image.open('bubble.png')
        self.resCard = cardPath.resize((100,100))
        self.CardVar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resCard,master=root)
```

> to this:

```
    self.cardPath = Image.open('bubble.png')
    self.resCard = cardPath.resize((100,100))
    self.CardVar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resCard)
```

---

## THE NEW ERROR

[*image form*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiUlh.png)

---

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3/animation_test.py', wdir='/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3')
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3/animation_test.py", line 56, in 
>       alien()
>
> File "/Users/Stian/.spyder-py3/animation_test.py", line 27, in **init**
>       self.alien2 = self.canvas.create_image(100,100,CardVar,anchor=CENTER)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2486, in create_image
>       return self._create('image', args, kw)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2477, in _create
>       *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
>
> TclError: unknown option "pyimage21"

Comment: We don't need to see the code or errors in image form. But it'd be nice if you supplied the "bubble.png" image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i edited the code and made it work. here is the full code

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import PIL
from PIL import Image,ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageTk

class alien(object):
    def __init__(self):

    self.root = Tk()
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=400, height = 400)
    self.canvas.pack()

    CardVar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='bubble.png')
    self.alien1 = self.canvas.create_oval(20, 260, 120, 360, outline='white',fill='blue')
    self.alien2 = self.canvas.create_image((100,100),image=CardVar,anchor=CENTER)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.root.after(0, self.animation)
    self.root.mainloop()


 def animation(self):
    track = 0
    while True:
        x = 5
        y = 0
        if track == 0:
           for i in range(0,51):
                time.sleep(0.025)
                self.canvas.move(self.alien1, x, y)
                self.canvas.move(self.alien2, x, y)
                self.canvas.update()
           track = 1
           print("check")

        else:
           for i in range(0,51):
                time.sleep(0.025)
                self.canvas.move(self.alien1, -x, y)
                self.canvas.move(self.alien2, -x, y)
                self.canvas.update()
           track = 0
        print(track)
alien()
```

**The problem**

> the cardVar was never able to find the correct image even though it was in the same folder, so i tried to do cardVar.show() and another image that was located far away showed up so it seems like something was saved in my memory. so i decided to *restart kernel* and everything went smooth

Answer (score 1):

You have a few places in your code where you forgot `self`. But the cause of your main error is that you need to pass the image name as a keyword arg. Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from PIL import Image,ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageTk

class alien(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.cardPath = Image.open('bubble.png')
        self.resCard = self.cardPath.resize((100, 100))
        self.CardVar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resCard)
        self.alien1 = self.canvas.create_oval(20, 260, 120, 360, outline='white', fill='blue')
        self.alien2 = self.canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=self.CardVar, anchor=CENTER)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.root.after(0, self.animation)
        self.root.mainloop()

     def animation(self):
        track = 0
        while True:
            x = 5
            y = 0
            if track == 0:
               for i in range(51):
                    time.sleep(0.025)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien1, x, y)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien2, x, y)
                    self.canvas.update()
               track = 1
               print("check")
            else:
               for i in range(51):
                    time.sleep(0.025)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien1, -x, y)
                    self.canvas.move(self.alien2, -x, y)
                    self.canvas.update()
               track = 0
            print(track)

alien()
```

BTW, it's not a good idea to use `time.sleep` in GUI programs. It puts *everything* to sleep, so the GUI cannot update itself, or respond to any user input. It would be better to reorganize your code so that `animation` uses the `.after` method.

Here's a version of the `animation` method that doesn't use `sleep`. You need to add `self.count = 0` to the `__init__` method.

```
 def animation(self):
    y = 0
    x = 5 if self.count < 50 else -5
    self.count = (self.count + 1) % 100
    self.canvas.move(self.alien1, x, y)
    self.canvas.move(self.alien2, x, y)
    self.root.after(25, self.animation)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it is greatly appreaciated! i did notice so too, the thing is that i've never had to assign it as a kwarg in my main application, but i decided to try it and it still gives me the same error. I also tried your code and still no luck unfortunately :(  

Also, thank you for your effort and the comment about using the time.sleep() in a GUI, will take a look into that aswell!  

Edit: would've 1 upped you if i had the power

Comment: @Stanley That's weird, it runs ok on my machine (using one of my own PNG images instead of bubble.png). Try running it on the command line directly, instead of inside Spyder.

Comment: Great idea! i did this and it seems like it cant locate bubble.png allthough you can see it in this picture: http://oi68.tinypic.com/fk5pfl.jpg

Comment: @Stanley Is "bubble.png" located in the same directory that you're launching the script from (which might _not_ be the directory containing the script)? If not, you should put it there. Or give the full path to "bubble.png" in your `Image.open` call.

Comment: It is the same directory, in the image posted above you can see both *bubble.png* and the .py script. I will try to give full path now and try to put it in a subfolder and get back to you, again. thanks!

Comment: Will definately do it when i get it to work ;)
But here is where it gets fuzzy. So i tried putting it in a sub folder and changed the path. still couldnt find the picture.

so i tried giving full path in the same folder, still couldnt find the picture.

But when i do this command in terminal it opens the picture: open /Users/Stian/.spyder-py3/bubble.png

Comment: UPDATE: i tried cardPath.show() to see if it could show the image and in that case there wouldve been an error inside PhotoImage. but there is no error, instead it opens the image file, but its a completely different image that is located far away on my computer

Comment: Figured it out, seems like another image was saved underneat cardVar in memory. restarted kernel and everything worked!

Comment: @Stanley Excellent! I'm glad you were able to solve this little mystery. :)